# How to send multiple MIDI Events over USB on iOs with Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, usb, midi, coremidi

I am using Core Midi to send MIDI Events over USB on a Xamarin iOs app,
I am based on this example
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/CoreMidiSample/

I want to modify the above example in order to send multiple NoteOn MIDI Events at the same time over USB, Unfortunately, It works only to send one NoteOn Midi Event at time,

Here is the modified part

```
void SendNote ()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Midi.DestinationCount; i++) {
                var endpoint = MidiEndpoint.GetDestination (i);
                // play note
                outputPort.Send (endpoint, new MidiPacket [] { new MidiPacket (0, new byte [] { 0x90, 60, 127 }) });
                outputPort.Send(endpoint, new MidiPacket[] { new MidiPacket(0, new byte[] { 0x90, 64, 127 }) });
                outputPort.Send(endpoint, new MidiPacket[] { new MidiPacket(0, new byte[] { 0x90, 68, 127 }) });
            }
        }
```

It sound only one note sometimes, sometimes two notes,
I would expect to get the three notes to sound at the same time always,
How can I do that?

Comment: What about `Sleep()`?

Comment: I just added Thread.Sleep(1); after every midi event, It works, so strange.

Comment: But there should be a way to send this 3 notes at the same time exactly because according to the documentation a MidiPacket can contain many midi events, but I dont know how.

Comment: What happens with a single sleep after the loop?

Comment: A single Sleep, also didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

A `MidiPacket` contains just a bunch of bytes to be sent. So you can concatenate them:

```
new byte [] { 0x90, 60, 127, 0x90, 64, 127, 0x90, 68, 127 }
```

or even use running status:

```
new byte [] { 0x90, 60, 127, 64, 127, 68, 127 }
```

Comment: I have already tried that in the past, both byte arrays, none of that worked, I get only the sound of one note, So Strange, because It should actually works.

Answer (score 0):

See the page below on midi.org - basically you need to enable 'poly mode'.

Channel Mode Messages

Controller numbers 124 through 127 are used to select between Omni Mode On or Off, and to select between the Mono Mode or Poly Mode of operation.

When Poly mode is selected, incoming Note On messages are played polyphonically. This means that when multiple Note On messages are received, each note is assigned its own voice (subject to the number of voices available in the synthesizer). The result is that multiple notes are played at the same time.

https://www.midi.org/articles-old/about-midi-part-3-midi-messages

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wonna, I tried sending Omni Mode On, or Poly mode On, events but this time I do not get any sound no note is played, I think somehow I can only send 1 midi event at a time.

Comment: I am not sure why is this happening, maybe is an issue with Camera Kit connection for iOs.